# How does wpf application settings actually work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

in my application I have easy login page with IP address / login / password / remember me checker.

When I check remember me, application stores these data in file in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\App\App.exe_Url_5b4qolbj3ip4ltms1ohyh4cdivud5wfg\1.0.0.0\user.config

That is totally fine for me but the problem is (that I have no idea why is that happening) when I build my SetupWizard.msi this user.config is created by application in app folder.

Then when I execute program, and check remember me box, it won't store values in this app created user.config but it is still stored in AppData file.

Is there any way how can I get rid of user.config in application folder and have it stored only in AppData? Also main reason for that is that this (created by instalation) config file have two extension: App.exe.config. There is no way I leave it like that in release.

Saving Code

```
        public void Save_data()
    {
        if (CheckBoxRemCredts.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.userName = txtBoxLogin.Text;
            Variable.passEncrypted = (Encrypt(pswBox.Password));
            //  MessageBox.Show(Variable.passEncrypted); Debugging
            Properties.Settings.Default.userPass = Variable.passEncrypted;
            Properties.Settings.Default.ipAddress = txtBoxIP.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Remme = "yes";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.userName = txtBoxLogin.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.userPass = pswBox.Password;
            Properties.Settings.Default.ipAddress = txtBoxIP.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Remme = "no";
            Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
        }
    }
```

Settings.settings file:

```
   namespace SMS_Vrána.Properties {


[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "15.7.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string userPass {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["userPass"]));
        }
        set {
            this["userPass"] = value;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string Remme {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Remme"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Remme"] = value;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string ipAddress {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["ipAddress"]));
        }
        set {
            this["ipAddress"] = value;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string userName {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["userName"]));
        }
        set {
            this["userName"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings scope. You can do it by right clicking on you project name in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Settings. Your code suggests that it is `User`. Here is why the settings may not be saved:

> There are two types of application settings, based on scope:
>
> - Application-scoped settings can be used for information such as a URL for a web service or a database connection string. These values
>     are associated with the application. Therefore, users cannot change
>     them at run time.
> - User-scoped settings can be used for information such as persisting the last position of a form or a font preference. Users can change
>     these values at run time.
>
> You can change the type of a setting by using the Scope property.
>
> The project system stores application settings in two XML files:
>
> - an app.config file, which is created at design time when you create    the first application setting
> - a user.config file, which is created at run time when the user who runs the application changes the value of any user setting.
>
> Notice that changes in user settings are not written to disk unless
>   the application specifically calls a method to do this.

More about Settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2017).

Comment: The `[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]` in the OP's code hints that the settings are indeed user-scoped.

Comment: I am so sorry, right now I noticed that I expressed myself bad. I don't want it in my instalation path. I would like to have that user.config only in AppData or atleast so it can be hidden in instalation path.

Comment: @Pati K don't you know what to do in that situation?

Comment: @Cabry Sorry, but not really. The only solution that comes to my mind is programatically deleting the file when it appears.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way how can I get rid of user.config in application folder and have it stored only in AppData? Also main reason for that is that this (created by instalation) config file have two extension: App.exe.config.

This is how .NET settings work. Your application needs both the `user.config` file if you have user-level settings, and it needs the `app.config` file if you have app-level settings. When the application creates a new file of user settings, it copies the `user.config` file from the installation folder to the `AppData\Local\` folder. Similarly, when it creates the `{APPNAME}.exe.config` file, it copies the one in the installation folder.

In short, there is no reason to delete (and plenty of reasons to keep) the `user.config` file in the application's installation folder.